# Mysql Query to choose current date on Specifc time zone

Tags: mysql, azure

I need to delete entries from my MySql table which is less than current date. I am using this query for that.

```
delete FROM Offers WHERE ed < DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE())
```

I am working on Windows Azure and my server is running on a different time zone. I am not seeing any option to change my MySql server time zone.

What is the query for calling `GETDATE()` function on a specific time zone.Or I need to convert current time to a specific time zone (I need gmt+5.30).

Can I get a query something like this , `delete FROM Offers WHERE ed < DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()+5.30)`

Comment: Add time difference  in your current time like that:- **DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)**

Comment: Just change your session time zone `SET SESSION time_zone = '+05:30'` before running your query

Answer (score 1):

You can set MySQL timezone by using this query

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5.30';//Your timezone 
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';//Your timezone name
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';//Your timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different timezone for current session like below. See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) for more information.

```
SET time_zone = timezone_name;
```

(OR) You can as well set global server timezone using

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone_name;
```